# how to output postback xml in form input tag

Tags: php, xml

I have a PHP application which sends data to a payment site via an html form, which has a hidden input field holding the value of an xml document. Here's a sample of the form:

```
<form action="http://www.paymentcompany.com/frmPayment.aspx" method="POST">
    <input type="hidden" name="request" value="&lt;?xml version=&quot;1.0&quot; encoding=&quot;utf-16&quot;?&gt;&lt;Request_v1  xmlns:xsi=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance&quot; xmlns:xsd=&quot;http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema&quot;&gt;
    &lt;Application&gt;
        &lt;ApplicationID&gt;testID123&lt;/ApplicationID&gt;
        &lt;LanguageID&gt;EN&lt;/LanguageID&gt;
    &lt;/Application&gt; />
</form>
```

When the user clicks the submit payment button, the data above is sent back (postback) to my application. I have tried to retrieve/output the data using the $_POST array, HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA and php://input but nothing seems to work (array is empty or get undefined index). Any advice or suggestions would be greatly appreciated. I'm new to online payment transactions and XML so I apologize if I didn't explain this clearly.

Comment: You didn't end your `<input />` tag and I don't believe the `value` attribute can span multiple lines.

Comment: Sorry, I just didn't include in the sample code. It's closed in the full version of the form code. Just wanted to show how the xml is used as the value of the hidden field. That's what's got me hung up.

Comment: Is the `XML` spanning across multiple lines?

Comment: yes, most of the xml spans different lines

Comment: Have you tried placing all of the XML on one line within the HTML `<input />` tag's `value` attribute and then checking the `$_POST['request']` variable in php?

Comment: Haven't tried putting the xml all on one line. When I check the $_POST['request'] currently, I get the undefined index for 'request'. Could having the xml without any breaks make a difference?

Comment: Yes, that could very well be the problem. Attributes are not supposed to span multiple lines within their `"` quotes.

Comment: Sounds good, I'll give that a try. Just FYI, I've received a report summary from the payment site showing the data that is sent back to the site. It's basically one long string with the name/value pairs. s